# Chrome - How to clear incognito pages from memory/history?

Tags: chrome-for-android, privacy

Short: As Chrome reopens the incognito pages/tabs after closing it (the browser, even after ending it in the "Active applications" list), how can one make sure those pages are forgotten by the phone?

Long: If an incognito page/tab is open and displayed in Chrome and Chrome is closed (by the home button), then Chrome remembers the page and shows it again next time Chrome is opened. As this can be unwanted (imagine visiting some website in incognito, then hours later opening the browser, let's say on a bus, and the incognito page is displayed again, for everyone to see, well at least the people standing/sitting behind you).

Ending Chrome in the active applications list does not change this behavior, neither clearing the Chrome app cache in the Application Manager. I found doing a "force stop" finally removes the traces (or at least does not show it when starting Chrome). Is there a simpler (official?) way to "forget" the incognito pages?

PS: It is similar with the Samsung Internet browser, except there not even "force stop" helps. (test on a Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3, Chrome 39.0.2171.93 , Internet 4.3-I9300XXUGNH4)

---

News:
With Chrome version 48.0.2564.95 it is different (arguably better):

- ending Chrome in "Active applications" makes it forget the incognito tabs
- also clearing the "last opened apps" list (not sure what the official names for this is. It is the recently open apps list one gets by holding the home button for a second) makes the incognito pages go away

Comment: Chrome 45.0 doesn't have this issue now.

Comment: I have 45.0.2454.84 now and it behaves still the same as described in the question.